# Old-style mapred API in HBase does not work

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I have a MapReduce job, which takes HBase table as the output destination
of my reduce job. My reducer class implements the `TableMap` interface in
package `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred`, and I used the `initTableReduceJob()`
function in `TableMapReduceUtil` class from
package `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred` to configure my job.

But when I run my job, I got the following error at reduce stage

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.getFsStatistics(Task.java:1099)
 at
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:490)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
 at
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

My HBase version is 0.94.0 and my Hadoop version is 1.0.1.

I found a post similar to my question at:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=394846

Could anyone give me some hint about why this happened? Should I just stick
with the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce` package?

Comment: Is the above issue resolved in your side? If yes, can you please let me know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests that you may be running HBase on the local filesystem without HDFS. Try installing or running Hadoop HDFS. The org.apache.hadoop.mapred API appears to require HDFS.

As a possible convenience, you may try the [Cloudera development VM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products.html?productID=F6mO278Rvo), which packages both.